# Qualities to look for in a PhD Supervisor

Tags: phd, advisor, united-kingdom

I am currently looking for a suitable PhD advisor in a relatively new and uncommon discipline which is only offered by a limited number of institutes, thus supervisors are of limited choices too. While it's a no-brainer that the most important thing to consider when choosing a PhD supervisor would be his/her research interest, I would love to know what would you think could be some other really important considerations too. Specifically, I am interested to know if you would prefer a well experienced supervisor (e.g. over 20 years supervising PhDs) over a recent PhD graduate (within 5 years for instance) and why. Thanks!

Comment: Also see e.g. [Choosing between an older, prominent supervisor and a younger, junior supervisor for PhD](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/96878/17254), [What are the risks and benefits of being the first PhD of a new supervisor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/168444/17254), [How should I take a potential PhD supervisor's age into account, when planning to follow PhD with habilitation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/24439/17254), [How important is it that your PhD advisor is an experienced, well-known faculty member?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/166731/17254)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anyon! Sorry for the duplication.